# How can I change this code to INSERT instead of UPDATE if content doesn't exist?

Tags: php, sql

I have a query that will update a row in the database, which works fine providing there is a row there to begin with.

How could I say; update if exists insert if doesn't?

```
    require_once('../scripts/includePDO.php');

    $who = $_SESSION['who'];
    $formText = $_POST['protext'];

$sql = "UPDATE tbl_profiles SET proText = :formText WHERE user_id = :who";

    $q   =  $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->bindValue(':who',$who,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $q->bindValue(':formText',$formText,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->execute();

header("Location: ../settings/?status=Done");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `user_id` is a unique key in the db:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_profiles (user_id, proText) VALUES (:who, :formText) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE proText = :formText";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query should be:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_profiles (user_id,proText) VALUES (:who,:formText)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE proText=:formText
```

This is assuming that user_ID is a unique id

Answer (score 0):

1- simple way is use ORM such as Dotrine
2- How ORM handle this :
usually tables has primary key(id) that should not be null .if you have update then you had select that load this data . in you select load id field in you data structure (array or object or something else) . in save method only check current row you want save that it has id (if this record has id then it exist and need to update else you should save).